# Neo4j - Performance: Find Nodes with a certain label with a relation to the source node

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

i have the following requirements:

- Given a source node
- Find all nodes within a certain range (e.g. 4 hops)
- and the destination nodes has a special label "x"
- Restrict the label type of the nodes in the path to the destination
- return only the shortest path length (e.g. if i find a node with 2 hops, dont find also nodes with 3 or 4 hops)
- Return all nodes needed for showing the destination nodes and the path between

i managed to create a query but the performance is not so well. i assume it is because of the high amount of nodes with the label "x"

```
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((source)-[*..4]-(destination))
WHERE source.objectID IN ['001614914']
AND source:Y
AND destination:X
AND ALL(x IN nodes(path)[1..] WHERE any(l in labels(x) WHERE l in ['A', 'B', 'C']))
WITH path
LIMIT 1000
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths, MIN(length(path)) AS minLength 
WITH FILTER(p IN paths WHERE length(p)= minLength) AS pathList
LIMIT 25
UNWIND pathList as path
WITH [n in nodes(path)] as nodes
return nodes
```

Profile:
[image: Profile with shortest path]

if i change the query to use not the shortest path function, this works well when the source has not a lot of outgoing Paths

```
MATCH path = ((source)-[*..4]-(destination))
WHERE source.objectID IN ['001614914']
AND source:Y
AND destination:X
AND ALL(x IN nodes(path)[1..] WHERE any(l in labels(x) WHERE l in ['A', 'B', 'C']))
WITH path
LIMIT 1000
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths, MIN(length(path)) AS minLength 
WITH FILTER(p IN paths WHERE length(p)= minLength) AS pathList
LIMIT 25
UNWIND pathList as path
WITH [n in nodes(path)] as nodes
return nodes
```

Profile:
[image: Profile without shortest path]

But if i have a source node with many children this has also a bad performance...

in the moment i am thinking if i start with a simple search for all destinations and call a shortestPath on each found destination this might be better but i am not very sure.

e.g.

```
MATCH (source)-[*..4]-(destination)
WHERE source.objectID IN ['001614914']
AND source:Y
AND destination:X
WITH destination
LIMIT 100
call apoc (shortest path ...)
...
```

Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try APOC's path expander using 'NODE_GLOBAL' uniqueness, it typically performs better than a variable-length match. It also has a means for whitelisting nodes during traversal, but this does apply to the start node too, so we'd have to include :Y in the whitelist.

See if this works for you:

```
MATCH path = (source:Y)
WHERE source.objectID IN ['001614914']
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(source, {labelFilter:'+A|B|C|Y', maxLevel:4, uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL'}) YIELD path
WITH path, last(nodes(path)) as destination
WHERE destination:X AND NONE(node in TAIL(nodes(path)) WHERE node:Y)
// all the rest is the same as your old query
WITH path
LIMIT 1000
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths, MIN(length(path)) AS minLength 
WITH FILTER(p IN paths WHERE length(p)= minLength) AS pathList
LIMIT 25
UNWIND pathList as path
RETURN NODES(path) as nodes
```

Comment: i try to convince my boss of the limitation ^^

Comment: There are some changes on their way on APOC which will make this kind of solution much easier, such as an option on whether or not to apply the label filter to the start node (so you won't need to specify 'Y' in the label filter), and the ability to use multiple filter operations at the same time (so you could specify the label of end-nodes for paths, as well as the whitelist). A limit operation is also on its way. Not sure about when a new release will happen but likely within the next two weeks or so.